# How can I create resource bundle with locale that doesn't have prefix?

Tags: java, localization, locale, resourcebundle

I have 3 property files

[Property files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QtQV.png)

How can I create ResourceBundle with locale that doesn't have prefix?
I know how to do It if locale has prefix.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en");
        ResourceBundle bundle1 = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources",locale);
```

Comment: I don't think there exists a locale without a prefix. What you probably want is to get a default resource bundle.

Comment: @pafauk. yes,it does.Thanks